# Writing a picture sliding game in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a picture sliding game using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. I did a 3*3 that worked fine, but for my 4*4, the picture pieces aren't showing up at all. This is the part of the HTML code that deals with the puzle, an example of how I've done by CSS, and my JS. I have my picture already broken up into pieces and the CSS is mostly for attaching each one to the respective piece. I know my HTML is reading the JS because I implemented a function just to see if it would read and it did. It isn't showing the picture of the puzzle, step count, etc.

HTML

```
<div class="text-center" style="padding-top:50px">
        <h2 id="stepCounter"></h2>
        <div id="table" class="text-center" style="display: table">
            <div id="row1" style="display: table-row;">
                <div id="book11" class="book1" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(1,1)"></div>
                <div id="book12" class="book2" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(1,2)"></div>
                <div id="book13" class="book3" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(1,3)"></div>
                <div id="book14" class="book4" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(1,4)"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row2" style="display: table-row;">
                <div id="book21" class="book5" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(2,1)"></div>
                <div id="book22" class="book6" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(2,2)"></div>
                <div id="book23" class="book7" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(2,3)"></div>
                <div id="book24" class="book8" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(2,4)"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row3" style="display: table-row;">
                <div id="book31" class="book9"  style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(3,1)"></div>
                <div id="book32" class="book10" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(3,2)"></div>
                <div id="book33" class="book11" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(3,3)"></div>
                <div id="book34" class="book12" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(3,4)"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row4" style="display: table-row;">
                <div id="book41" class="book13" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(4,1)"></div>
                <div id="book42" class="book14" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(4,2)"></div>
                <div id="book43" class="book15" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(4,3)"></div>
                <div id="book44" class="book16" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectBook(4,4)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.book1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #F5EDDA;
}
.book2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url(Pictures/book2/book22.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.book3 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url(Pictures/book2/book23.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.book4 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url(Pictures/book2/book24.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.book5 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url(Pictures/book2/book25.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.book6 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url(Pictures/book2/book26.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

JS

```
var stepCount = 0;

function shuffle() {
    for (var row = 1; row <= 4; row++) {
        for (var col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
            var row2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
            var col2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
            swapBook("book" + row + col, "book" + row2 + col2);
        }
    }
    stepCount = 0;
    document.getElementById('stepCounter').innerHTML = "<h2>Steps: </h2>" + stepCount;
}

function selectBook(row, col) {
    var book = document.getElementById("book" + row + col);
    var blankBook = book.className;

    if (blankBook != "book1") {
        //Checking if white tile on the right
        if (col < 4) {
            if (document.getElementById("book" + row + (col + 1)).className == "book1") {
                swapBook("book" + row + col, "book" + row + (col + 1));
                stepCount++;
                document.getElementById('stepCounter').innerHTML = "<h2>Steps: </h2>" + stepCount;
                return;
            }
        }
        //Checking if white tile on the left
        if (col > 1) {
            if (document.getElementById("book" + row + (col - 1)).className == "book1") {
                swapBook("book" + row + col, "book" + row + (col - 1));
                stepCount++;
                document.getElementById('stepCounter').innerHTML = "<h2>Steps: </h2>" + stepCount;
                return;
            }
        }
        //Checking if white tile is above
        if (row > 1) {
            if (document.getElementById("book" + (row - 1) + col).className == "book1") {
                swapBook("book" + row + col, "book" + (row - 1) + col);
                stepCount++;
                document.getElementById('stepCounter').innerHTML = "<h2>Steps: </h2>" + stepCount;
                return;
            }
        }
        //Checking if white tile is below
        if (row < 4) {
            if (document.getElementById("book" + (row + 1) + col).className == "book1") {
                swapBook("book" + row + col, "book" + (row + 1) + col);
                stepCount++;
                document.getElementById('stepCounter').innerHTML = "<h2>Steps: </h2>" + stepCount;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

function swapBook(book1, book2) {
    var temp = document.getElementById(book1).className;
    document.getElementById(book1).className = document.getElementById(book2).className;
    document.getElementById(book2).className = temp;
}
```

This is an example of my 3*3 HTML that works:

```
    <div class="text-center" style="padding-top:50px">
        <h2 id="stepCounter"></h2>
        <center>
            <div id="table" class="text-center" style="display: table">
                <div id="row1" style="display: table-row;">
                    <div id="piece11" class="piece1" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(1,1)"></div>
                    <div id="piece12" class="piece2" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(1,2)"></div>
                    <div id="piece13" class="piece3" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(1,3)"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="row2" style="display: table-row;">
                    <div id="piece21" class="piece4" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(2,1)"></div>
                    <div id="piece22" class="piece5" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(2,2)"></div>
                    <div id="piece23" class="piece6" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(2,3)"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="row3" style="display: table-row;">
                    <div id="piece31" class="piece7" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(3,1)"></div>
                    <div id="piece32" class="piece8" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(3,2)"></div>
                    <div id="piece33" class="piece9" style="display: table-cell;" onclick="selectPiece(3,3)"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

3*3 Working CSS

```
.piece1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #F5EDDA;
}
.piece2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url(Pictures/flower/flower2.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.piece3 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url(Pictures/flower/flower3.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
}
.piece4 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url(Pictures/flower/flower4.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Can you put up a code snippet Illustrating the problem, Also a code snippet the code that works `your 3*3` to see what is meant to happen.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I added my HTML and CSS of my working one, I've done everything exactly the same besides adding the extra rows and columns so I'm not sure what the problem is, it just skips right over my picture pieces and goes to execute the unrelated code below it.

Comment: I just ran your code with some placeholder pictures and everything works fine, i'm not sure What's the problem here, Again put a code snippet Illustrating the issue maybe on CodePen or jsfiddle

Comment: As @ZohirSalak said it is working properly for me as well. Maybe it is caused by your image directory. Also try assigning background color in your css to check if it working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the 4*4 CSS you take the images all from:

> Pictures/book2/

Whereas in your 3*3 you take the images from:

> Pictures/flower/

Are you possibly getting your files from the wrong folders?

If not, check your file names and see if they match up.